# Solutions of $\lfloor 4x\rfloor+\lfloor 3x\rfloor=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find all solutions of $$\lfloor 4x\rfloor+\lfloor 3x\rfloor=1$$

I have no idea as to how to go about this question. I would be grateful if somebody would please show me how to solve such questions.

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes Sir, it is the floor function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $x\le0$, then the LHS is non-positive.

So $x$ has to be positive. Since both terms on the LHS are integers with $\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le \lfloor 4x\rfloor$, we have 
$$\lfloor 4x\rfloor=1\quad \text{and}\quad \lfloor 3x\rfloor =0$$
from which $\color{red}{1/4\le x\lt 1/3}$ follows.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? I couldn't understand the part about $\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le \lfloor 4x\rfloor$. $$$$How do we compare between $\lfloor ax\rfloor$ and $\lfloor bx\rfloor$ for any general $x$ (ie positive or negative values of $x$), where $a,b$ are constants?

Comment: @user342209  : For $x\gt 0$, we have $3x\lt 4x$, and so $\lfloor 3x\rfloor\le \lfloor 4x\rfloor$. Does this help or not?

Comment: @user342209: In general, if $ax\le bx$, then $\lfloor ax\rfloor\le\lfloor bx\rfloor$.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was typing on my phone.

Comment: @user342209: You may want to see the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(x)) of floor function.

Comment: @mathlove It helps a lot!

Comment: @mathlove Sir could you please tell me what I'm to interpret from the graph? Thanks!

Comment: @user342209: Choose any two real numbers $a,b$ with $a\lt b$. Do you see that $\lfloor a\rfloor \color{red}{\le}\lfloor b\rfloor$ always holds?

Comment: @mathlove Oh yes, I saw that sir. I thought that graphically you were showing a solution to the initial problem I had posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$\lfloor4x \rfloor+\lfloor3x \rfloor=1$$
$$4x-1<\lfloor4x \rfloor\le4x$$
$$3x-1<\lfloor3x \rfloor\le3x$$
Then $$3x+4x-2<\lfloor4x \rfloor+\lfloor3x \rfloor\le3x+4x$$
$$7x-2\le1<7x$$
$$\frac 17< x\le\frac37$$

Case 1) $\frac 17< x<\frac14$

Case 2) $\frac 14\le x<\frac13$

Case 3) $\frac 13\le x<\frac37$

Answer: $$\frac 14\le x<\frac13$$

Comment: Sir, isn't $[x]\le x$? Then how can $4x\le\lfloor4x \rfloor<4x+1$?

Comment: You probably mean $4x-1$ and $4x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a+b=1$ where $a,b\in \Bbb{Z}$.

Note if $x <0$ then $\lfloor 3x\rfloor<0$ and likewise with $4x$. So $a,b\geq 0$.

So the equation boils down to $a=1$ and $b=0$ or vice versa. Note that $\lfloor 4x\rfloor\geq \lfloor 3x\rfloor$ so you need to find $x$ so that $\lfloor 3x\rfloor=0$ and $ \lfloor 4x \rfloor = 1$.

You want $0<3x<1$ and $1\leq 4x< 2$. That is, $1/4 \leq x < 1/3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor\mathrm{4}{x}\rfloor+\lfloor\mathrm{3}{x}\rfloor=\mathrm{1}$$
$$\mathrm{4}{x}=\left[\mathrm{1};\mathrm{2}\right),\:\mathrm{3}{x}=\left[\mathrm{0};\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $$
$${x}=\left[\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}};\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{2}}\right)\cap\left[\mathrm{0};\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{3}}\right) \\ $$
$${x}=\left[\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{4}};\frac{\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{3}}\right) \\ $$